# What should I do to plot wavelets on Octave?

Tags: math, octave

I am studying Wavelets and making notes with octave, I wish I could have my own graphs that represent the annotated raw Wavelets, I saw that in MathLab has a function that plots the wavelets, just enter the name of the desired wavelet.

[image]
Is there any function in Octave (any of its packages) that does such a plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of wavelet functions in the `signal` package, that if you want to avoid compiling from source can be installed with `pkg install -forge signal` or with `apt-get install octave-signal` if you use Ubuntu. You can use it as follows:

```
pkg load signal

lb = -4;
ub = 4;
n = 1000;
[psi,xval] = morlet(lb,ub,n);
plot(xval,psi,"linewidth",4)
grid on
```

[image]

You can find a list of available wavelet functions in the signal package [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/overview.html).

Comment: There are no Daubechs Wavelets in the list, but it has helped to better understand how Octave handles the issue, I believe I can use the tlfat functions the same way, thanks.